# When saving a model, data in $.ajaxSetup is not merged

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have an Ember.js app backed by a RESTful API. Session control is done through an authentication token: once a user logs in, he appends his authentication token to each request he makes to the server. I do this by adding the authentication to the data in `$.ajaxSetup`.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  data: { auth_token: this.get('authToken') }
});
```

Now, this works fine for GET requests. However, when saving models to the server through a POST or PUT request, the Ember Data RESTAdapter stringifies the data object. In `DS.RESTAdapter.ajax` it does

```
....
if (hash.data && type !== 'GET') {
  hash.contentType = 'application/json; charset=utf-8';
  hash.data = JSON.stringify(hash.data);
}
...
```

Because of this, the authentication token is not merged into the data. In [this jQuery ticket](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11224) they say that it's something they are never going to support.

What's the most elegant way of solving this? I'd rather not override the Ember's `RESTAdapter.ajax` function because the code is changing so quickly so my overridden function might not be compatible with the rest of the codebase at the next release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I couldn't find another solution besides overriding `RESTAdapter.ajax`. I ended up adding three parameters: `auth[token]`, `auth[school]` and `auth[name]`.

```
DS.RESTAdapter.reopen({
  /* Override to add the authToken, school and name */
  ajax: function(url, type, hash) { 
    var adapter = this;

    return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) { 
      hash = hash || {};
      hash.url = url;
      hash.type = type;
      hash.dataType = 'json';
      hash.context = adapter;

      if (hash.data && type !== 'GET') { 
        hash.contentType = 'application/json; charset=utf-8';

        /* Add the data to the hash before it's stringified. */
        if (HstryEd.Session.get('isLoggedIn')) { 
          hash.data.auth = {};
          hash.data.auth.token = HstryEd.Session.get('authToken');
          hash.data.auth.school = HstryEd.Session.get('currentUser').get('school');
          hash.data.auth.name = HstryEd.Session.get('currentUser').get('name');
        } 

        hash.data = JSON.stringify(hash.data);
      } 

      if (adapter.headers !== undefined) { 
        var headers = adapter.headers;
        hash.beforeSend = function (xhr) { 
          forEach.call(Ember.keys(headers), function(key) { 
            xhr.setRequestHeader(key, headers[key]);
          });
        };
      } 

      hash.success = function(json) { 
        Ember.run(null, resolve, json);
      };

      hash.error = function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
        if (jqXHR) { 
          jqXHR.then = null;
        } 

        Ember.run(null, reject, jqXHR);
      };

      Ember.$.ajax(hash);
    });
  } 
});
```